# If $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, is it true that $x< y \Leftrightarrow x^{n}<y^{n}$ for each natural number $n$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

Im trying to prove the following:

'"If $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, then $x< y  \Leftrightarrow x^{n}<y^{n}$ for each natural number $n$"

I found the forward direction easy to prove with induction but don't know how to prove the backward direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Prove the contrapositive: if $x\ge y$, then $x^n\ge y^n$.

*Variant*:

You can prove both ways in one go, without induction, observing it amounts to proving that, for a positive number $u$, $u>1\iff u^n>1$.

Indeed, set $\dfrac yx=u$ and use the algebraic identity
$$u^n-1=(u-1)(u^{n-1}+\dots+u+1).$$

Answer (score 2):

Prove and use the following lemma.

If $a>b>0$ and $c>d>0$ then $ac>bd$.

Answer (score 0):

In case you know that $x\mapsto x^n$ is injective and continuous  on $(0,\infty)$ you may use the well known fact that injective continuous  functions defined on an interval are strictly monoton.